# Unable to find logic behind question on primes.

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime number and $s$ be a positive integer. Show that for any $i \in \{0, 1, . . . , p^s− 1\},\ \binom{p^s−1}i \equiv (−1)^i(mod\ p)$.

Formula-wise the question attempts to take the ratio of:
$\frac{(p^s−1)!}{i!(p^s−1-i)!}$, for all $i\in \{0, 1, . . . , p^s− 1\}$.

On taking some special values of $i$, get the below:
1. If $i=0$, the ratio =$1$, 
2. If $i=1$, the ratio =$p^s−1$, 
3. If $i=p^s−1$, the ratio =$1$,

But am unable to understand what is the logical implication of the question; and why only prime value of $p$ is considered.

Also, suggest an approach to solve the same.

Comment: Proof by induction should work - look at the ratio between ${p^s-1}\choose i$ and ${p^s-1}\choose {i+1}$ and consider cases based on whether $i+1$ is a multiple of $p$.

Comment: @Karl But, why only prime values for $p$ is unclear. Also, any logical implication of the question.

Comment: The proof I have in mind uses the primality of $p$ to ensure that all the factors in the denominator that are not 0 mod $p$ have inverses mod $p$. What do you mean by logical implication?

Comment: @Karl By logical implication, mean that the property highlighted by the problem. I hope your comment shows the logical implication of the problem. Also, please post answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely agree with Siong Thye Goh's answer and consider his answer **more elegant** than the one I am about to present.  My *answer* is intended to show the **much more pedestrian and inelegant but still viable approach** of induction.

Assume that the conjecture is true for $i$, where 
$0 \leq i \leq p^s - 2.$
Then $\;\binom{p^s - 1}{i + 1},\;$ which is an integer, equals
$\;\binom{p^s - 1}{i} \times \frac{p^s - [i+1]}{i + 1}.$

By inductive assumption, $\;\binom{p^s - 1}{i} \;\equiv (-1)^i \pmod{p}.$
Further, $\;(-1)^i [-(i+1)] \equiv (i+1)(-1)^{(i+1)} \pmod{p}
\;\Rightarrow$
$\;\binom{p^s - 1}{i} \times [p^s - (i+1)]
\;\equiv\; (i + 1) (-1)^{(i+1)}\pmod{p} \;\Rightarrow$
$\;\binom{p^s - 1}{i} \times \frac{p^s - [i+1]}{i + 1}
\;\equiv\; (-1)^{(i+1)}\pmod{p}.$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
As Karl indicated in his comment below, I must examine the case of 
$\;(i+1) \;\equiv\; 0 \pmod{p}\;$ separately.  I am working on it and will update my answer if and when I find a remedy.

Convoluted remedy found : proof by contradiction.

Let $pk$ denote the smallest multiple of $p$ such that the conjecture is false.  
Then, from the induction used in the first part of this answer, the conjecture is true for $i = (pk - 1).$

Let $v_p(n) \;\equiv\;$ the largest exponent $\theta$ such that 
$p^{\theta} | n.$ 
Let $v_p[(p^s - 1)!] = \alpha, \;v_p[(pk - 1)!] = \beta, 
\;v_p[(p^s - pk)!] = \gamma,\;$ and $\;v_p(pk) = \delta.$ 
By assumption, $\;\binom{p^s - 1}{pk-1} \;\equiv\; (-1)^{(pk-1)}
\;\pmod{p}.$

Therefore, $\;\alpha = \beta + \gamma,\; 
(p^s - 1)!\;$ has form $\;(p^\alpha) \times a,$ 
$(pk-1)!(p^s - pk)!\;$ has form $\;(p^\alpha) \times b,$ 
where $p$ does not divide $a$ or $b$ and
$a \equiv b\times (-1)^{(pk-1)} \pmod{p}.$

$v_p(pk) = \delta \;\Rightarrow v_p(p^s - pk) = \delta.$ 
Further, $\;pk = p^\delta \times r,\;$ where 
$p$ does not divide $r \;\Rightarrow\;$ 
$(p^s - pk)\;$ will have form $(p^\delta) \times (-t),\;$
where $\;t \;\equiv\; r \pmod{p}.$

Thus, $\;(pk)!(p^s - 1 - pk)! \;=\; $
$(pk) \times [(pk-1)!]\times\frac{(p^s - pk)!}{(p^s - pk)},$ 
which can be re-expressed as $(p^\delta \times r) \times (p^\alpha \times b)$
$\frac{1}{p^\delta\times(-t)} \;\Rightarrow\;$ 
$\binom{p^s - 1}{pk} \;\equiv\; (-1)^{(pk-1)} \times \frac{-t}{r} 
\;\equiv\; (-1)^{(pk)} \pmod{p}.$ 
This yields a contradiction. Therefore, the conjecture **also** holds for any $i < p^s - 1,$ 
where $i$ is a multiple of $p$.

Comment: Siong Thye Goh's answer was: \begin{align}
\binom{p^s-1}{i} &= \frac{\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}(p^s-1-j)}{i!}\\&\equiv \frac{\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}(-1-j)}{i!} \pmod{p}\\
&\equiv \frac{(-1)^i i!}{i!} \pmod{p}\\
&\equiv (-1)^i \pmod{p}
\end{align}

I don't think $p$ being prime is needed.

Comment: You're dividing both sides by 0 in the last step when $i+1$ is a multiple of $p$. The deleted answer was wrong for the same reason.

Comment: Notice that $\binom{6^1-1}2=\binom52=10\equiv4\not\equiv(-1)^2\pmod6$, so primality must be used.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. :)

Comment: @Karl Nice catch; see my addendum.

Comment: @Karl hopefully my remedy (in the addendum) is valid.

Comment: Please elaborate the significance of introducing four symbols in the line: Let $v_p[(p^s - 1)!] = \alpha, \;v_p[(pk - 1)!] = \beta, 
\;v_p[(p^s - pk)!] = \gamma,\;$ and $\;v_p(pk) = \delta.$

Comment: @jiten $v_p(pk) = \delta\;$ signifies that $pk$ can be expressed as $p^\delta \times r$, where $p$ does not divide $r$.  The rest of the line signifies that $\;\binom{p^s - 1}{pk - 1}$ can be expressed as $\frac{p^\alpha \times a}{p^{(\beta + \gamma)} \times b},\;$ where $p$ does not divide $a$ or $b$.

Comment: I present my version of your comment: $v_p(pk)=\delta$ signifies that $pk$ can be expressed as $p^{\delta} \times r$, where $p\not \mid r$. Need the value of $\binom{p^s-1}{pk-1}$, for which in turn need $3$ terms (total of $4$): $p^s-1, pk-1, p^s-pk$. But, have a multiplier term of $v_p=\theta$ with these $3(4)$ terms, as $p^{\theta} \mid n$. Here, have an addtl. difficulty:: why $v_p$ is shown as multiplier to the four terms?

Comment: @jiten In your last comment, your 1st sentence expresses what I am trying to say.  Unsure about your question in remainder of comment.  I chose this approach, because in order to establish the contradiction expressed in my answer's addendum, I first have to determine (with respect to $\binom{p^s - 1}{pk - 1}$), the largest exponent $\theta_1$ such that $p^{\theta_1}$ divides the numerator.  I similarly must find the largest exponent $\theta_2$ such that $p^{\theta_2}$ divides the denominator.  Then, I have to establish the relationship between $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.  See next comment.

Comment: @jiten If you examine the first part of my answer, and then examine Karl's subsequent comment (re my answer had a flaw), I must take special steps in the addendum to establish a contradiction.  When completing the addendum, I was unaware of Karl's answer.  If you compare my addendum to his answer, you will see very similar analysis.

Comment: I request your attention to the source of the problem, and the solution provided there:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h1Nl.png. I am not sure how the author made the answer, but was not aware of the question's significance; so placed this question.

Comment: @jiten what you are referring to seems to be an **elegant** approach.  Please re-read the first part of my answer.  The whole point was to show that the **inelegant** induction approach, which (as in this case) often requires **much less creativity** is **often viable.**

Comment: I am still trying to understand your proof, and request to be in chat at : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105935/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten Will be waiting there for you to arrive.

Comment: I am in chatroom from here to many hours.

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to show that $\binom{p^s-1}{i+1}\equiv(-1)\binom{p^s-1}i\pmod p$.

Write $i+1=p^kr$ where $p\not\mid r$. Since $p$ is prime and $p\not\mid r$, we have $\gcd(p,r)=1$, so there exists an integer $r^{-1}$ such that $r^{-1}r\equiv1\pmod p$. Also note that $k<s$, so $p^{s-k}\equiv0\pmod p$.

*Without* reducing mod $p$, we can verify the following equality of integers:
$$
r\binom{p^s-1}{i+1}=(p^{s-k}-r)\binom{p^s-1}i
$$

Then multiplying both sides by $r^{-1}$ and reducing mod $p$ using the observations above gives the desired result.

Comment: Please elaborate how it is always possible to write $i+1 = p^kr$, where $p\not\mid r$.

Comment: Starting with $i+1$, keep dividing by $p$ until you can't.

Comment: In other words, take the largest $k$ such that $p^k\mid{i+1}$.

Comment: I hope you mean $$r\binom{p^s-1}{i+1}=(p^{s-k}-r)\binom{p^s-1}i=(-1)^{(i+1)}(mod \ p)$$ If am correct, still request elaboration of the same.

Comment: By "multiply both sides by $r^{-1}$ and reduce mod $p$", I mean you could write $\binom{p^s-1}{i+1}\equiv r^{-1}r\binom{p^s-1}{i+1}=r^{-1}(p^{s-k}-r)\binom{p^s-1}i\equiv r^{-1}(0-r)\binom{p^s-1}i\equiv(-1)\binom{p^s-1}i$. Note the difference between $=$ and $\equiv$. By "It suffices to show that X", I meant that once we've shown X, the requested result follows by induction.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the symbol $\equiv$ is used here for showing equivalent results (terms), rather than equality. It shows that induction is used to get equivalent terms. I hope then your last comment must be read as: $\binom{p^s-1}{i+1} \equiv r^{-1} r \binom{p^s-1}{i+1} \equiv r^{-1} (p^{s-k}-r)\binom{p^s-1}{i} \equiv r^{-1}(0- r) \binom{p^s-1}{i} \equiv (-1) \binom{p^s-1}{i}$.

Comment: The places where I used $=$ (including the one in my last comment) are actual equalities, meaning that two expressions denote the same integer. Equality implies modular congruence, so what you wrote is also true. Keep in mind that "$x\equiv y\pmod p$" is short for "$p\mid{x-y}$".

Answer (score 1):

Let $$v=\binom{p^s-1}{i} = \frac{\prod_{j=1}^{i}(p^s-j)}{i!}$$

Suppose $j \in \{1, i\}$, we can write $j=p^{r_j}w_j$ where $gcd(p,w_j)=1$, $r_j < s$, then $$p^s-j=p^s-p^{r_j}w_j=p^{r_j}(p^{s-r_j}-w_j)$$

$$v=\prod_{j=1}^i\left(\frac{p^s-j}{j}\right)=\prod_{j=1}^i\left( \frac{p^{r_j}(p^{s-r_j}-w_j)}{p^{r_j}w_j}\right)=\prod_{j=1}^i\left( \frac{p^{s-r_j}-w_j}{w_j}\right)$$

$$v\cdot \prod_{j=1}^iw_j = \prod_{j=1}^i (p^{s-r_j}-w_j)$$

$$v\cdot \prod_{j=1}^iw_j \equiv  \prod_{j=1}^i (p^{s-r_j}-w_j) \equiv  \prod_{j=1}^i (-w_j)\equiv (-1)^i \prod_{j=1}^iw_j \pmod{p}$$

Since $gcd(p,w_j)=1$, $\left(\prod_{j=1}^iw_j\right)^{-1}$ exists, multiplying it on the both sides, we have

$$v \equiv (-1)^i \pmod{p}$$

That is 
$$\binom{p^s-1}{i}\equiv (-1)^i \pmod{p}$$

---

Remark: I made a mistake earlier for not checking if an element is invertible.

This is the **wrong** approach:

\begin{align}
\binom{p^s-1}{i} &= \left(\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}(p^s-1-j)\right)(i!)^{-1}\\
&\equiv \left(\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}(-1-j)\right)(i!)^{-1} \equiv (-1)^i(i!)(i!)^{-1}  \\&\equiv (-1)^i \pmod{p}
\end{align}

because I did not check that $(i!)^{-1}$ exists and indeed it need not exists.

In my latest approach, I ensure that $gcd(w_j,p)=1$ and hence $(\prod_j w_j)^{-1}$ exists. Also, by expressing $j=p^{r_j}w_j$, I have illustated that the $p^{r_j}$ factor  in $p^s-j$ can cancel out with $p^{r_j}$ factor in $j$.

That is now I use the property that the

- $p^{r_1}$ in $1$ and $p^s-1$ cancels out.
- $p^{r_2}$ in $2$ and $p^s-2$ cancels out

and so on.

Comment: How to show that the condition of $p$ being a prime is unneeded.

Comment: Does my proof use any prime property?

Comment: Please elaborate your first answer line, that shows it as a product of terms in the numerator.

Comment: I hope that once the condition for $p$ being a prime is shown as redundant, there is no special logic attached to the question; just an application of the binomial theorem.

Comment: The numerator is just $\frac{(p^s-1)!}{(p^s-1-i)!}$.  Perhaps the intended proof uses stuff that involves prime number property like Wilson's theorem? Anyway, do check numerically for a few numbers. I haven't gave it sufficient thought yet and I might make mistakes.

Comment: I see, @jiten kindly remove the acceptance and I will delete the post.

Comment: Our discussion is in chat room : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105935/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten

Comment: Please be back in chatroom. As it is an abstract area, so have no idea about coding in it. Even a simpler program can help to build better ones.

Comment: Please be back in chatroom. Have failed as tried your wrong (but, easier) version, answer is $0$. Only your help can make it work by implementing correct version.

Comment: @jiten it is now 11:17am pacific standard time.  i will be back in the chat room at 2pm pacific standard time.

Comment: My first version of correct code: https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user305_zg4lA8zMse_2.py; yours' benchmark is at: https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user305_JiODDeBcQcRCYUL.py

Comment: Please see my last comment to selected answer to my today's post at:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3600042/424260 It attempts an extension of the question to $n^{34}-b$, where $b$ is not expressible as a square.

Comment: out of respect of the other users, it's not appropriate for me to interfere now.

Comment: Please be in chatroom for my updated answer for Q.6. Also, posted at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3606900/424260.

Comment: Please be in chatroom.