# Prove that $n^{34}-9$ is never prime for any $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

It is given in the book 'Introduction to Number Theory' by 'William W. Adams, Larry Joel Goldstein' as Q. 17 in sec. 2.4 (titled: Unique Factorization) exercise:

Prove that $n^{34}-9$ is never prime for any $n$.

If $n$ is prime, then any power of it wouldn't be a prime. But, what is the significance of subtracting $9$ from $n^{34}$ is not clear.

Comment: It is simple. $(n^{17}-3)(n^{17}+3)$ can not be prime.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That post has got no response like the selected answer, and it is the answer that is needed too, apart from the question. There is no harm if a more correct (here, generally applicable) answer is got here. This fills the need to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ is never prime for integers $a,b$, unless either $a+b$ or $a-b$ is $\pm 1$.

Comment: Please vet my explanation of your answer: If $a-b=\pm1$, then four cases emerge for $a+b$, based on two factors: (i) which of $a,b$ is prime, (ii) which is bigger, also the difference is $1$ only: (a) $a>b$ & $a$ is prime:  $(a+b)= 2a+1$, which is not guaranteed to be prime; (b) $a>b$ & $b$ is prime:  $(a+b)= 2b+3$, which is not guaranteed to be prime; (c) $a<b$ & $a$ is prime, (iv) $a<b$ and $b$ is prime. Th last two cases can be handled like for (i) & (ii).

Comment: @jiten I don't think so. None of this depends on whether or not $a$ and $b$ are prime. It's just that, unless $a=\pm b\pm1$, both $a+b$ and $a-b$ will be greater than $1$ in absolute value, so their product will be a composite number.

Comment: Yes, thanks for vetting & pointing out the error.

Comment: Can this question be extended to $n^{34}-b$ where $b$ cannot be expressed as a square of a natural? Say, $b=17$,

Comment: @jiten that's possible, but we certainly don't have such an easy solution as in this case. In fact, I think the expression $n^{34}-17$ attains prime values infinitely often, but if I'm not wrong this is only conjectured and not known. (Well, if it is known, I don't know a proof.)

Answer (score 1):

$(n^{34} - 9)$ can be express as $(n^{17}-3)(n^{17}+3)$ so it is not prime $\forall n$